# Why doesn't this PL/SQL procedure work?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

I have a cursor which returns two values: one which I will use (and therefore will assign to an `out` variable) and another which I've only had returned to make the ROWNUM thing work.

If I run the cursor as a query, it works as expected. But if I execute the procedure the `out` variable comes empty. Is my approach somehow not supported? I mean, returning two values but only using one of them?

Here is my procedure code: (Don't delve too much on the query itself. It works, I know it's a bit ugly but it works. It was the only way I found to return the *second-last* row)

```
procedure retorna_infos_tabela_164(i_nip in varchar,
                               o_CODSDPANTERIOR out number) is
cursor c_tabela_164 is
    select *
    from(
        select CODSDP,ROWNUM rn
        from
              (
                select NRONIP,CODTIPOMOV,CODSDP
                from TB164_HISTORICOMOVIMENTACOES
                where NRONIP = i_nip and
                CODTIPOMOV='S1'
                order by DTHMOV desc
              )
        )
    where rn=2;

    v_temp_nr number;

begin
    open c_tabela_164;
    fetch c_tabela_164 into o_CODSDPANTERIOR,v_temp_nr;
    close c_tabela_164;
end retorna_infos_tabela_164;
```

**EDIT** The way I've tried to run this procedure was by `dbms_output.put_line(o_CODSDPANTERIOR)` which didn't work. Then I googled a little bit and saw I should `TO_CHAR()` my var first and then have it output. Didn't work either.

Comment: Is it possible to run the cursor as a query? (in sybase it isn't)

Comment: @aF you can run it if you cut off the part before the `select` keyword. :)

Comment: Well I thought cursors *were* queries. You can just ctrl+c then ctrl+v in the sql runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I've had you guys take the time to answer me when the answer was something to do with the tool I'm using. I hope all you guys have learnt something.

The query does work for me at least, I've not come across any edge cases where it doesn't work, but I haven't tested it exhaustively.

The **problem** was that **TOAD**, the tool I'm using to run the procedures, sometimes populates the procedures with the parameters I tell it to but sometimes it doesn't. The issue here was that I was trying to execute the procedure with no parameters, yielding no results...

Lesson Learnt: double check the generated procedure code when you run a Procedure using Right Click > Run Procedure on TOAD version 9.

Comment: perhaps another lesson -- switch to a bare-bones tool like SQLPlus when your GUI tool gives unexpected results

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with passing a number to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`.  Oracle will silently convert other built-in types to `VARCHAR2` using the default format.  You only need to use `TO_CHAR` if you want to control the format used -- which is often a good idea, but not generally necessary.

One possibility, though, is that you are not seeing the output because you have not enabled it.  If you are running your test in SQLPlus, make sure you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before running code that includes DBMS_OUTPUT calls.  If you are using some other client, consult its documentation for the proper way to enable DBMS_OUTPUT.  (You can of course test if it's enabled by adding another call to output a string literal.)

There's nothing inherently wrong with the technique you're using to populate the out parameter.  However, it's not necessary to return two columns from the cursor; your `select *` could simply be `select CODSDP`.  You seem to be under the misconception that any column referenced in the predicates has to be in the select list, but that's not the case.  In your innermost query, the select list does not need to include `NRONIP` or `CODTIPOMOV`, because they are not referenced in the outer blocks; the WHERE clause in that query can reference any column in the table, regardless of whether it is in the select list.

So, my first guess is that you simply don't have server output enabled.  The only other possibility I can think of right now is that you're running your query and the procedure in two different sessions, and one of them has uncommitted transaction against the table, so they are actually seeing different data.

If those suggestions don't seem to be the problem, I'd suggest you run your tests of the standalone query and the procedure in a single SQLPlus session, then copy and paste the entire session here, so we can see exactly what you're doing.